# Visual Studio 2010: How do I create a solution with 2 projects, but have one DLL compile?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, assemblies, projects-and-solutions

Basically, I have a solution with multiple project files (DLLs in it). I want to compile the solution so that I don't have to hand out 3 different DLL files. I'd like to combine those into ONE DLL file. Is there any VS 2010 built in way of saying for these projects to work together to produce ONE DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ... too bad VS doesn't have that option built into it and needs to call an external app.

Comment: @michael: That's because needing to combine multiple assemblies into a single DLL is an extremely *unusual* case in the world of .NET and managed code. Why do you feel like you need to do this at all? There might be a better way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this. Why not merge the projects into sub folders within one solution?

Answer (score 0):

if your projects are ASP.NET projects then it can be done using the [ASP.NET Merge Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397866.aspx) (Aspnet_merge.exe) but I dont believe it can be done on non ASP.NET projects